# Database Shrink Doesn't Work

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

We have a database of 500GB with 70% free space after deleting some data. But it doesn't shrink!
I have tested different methods mentioned around the Web, such as incremental shrink (using a script), adding a few MBs to data files manually and so on.
But each time it fails with the same error 'File ID 7 from database 4 can not be ...'

The bad part is that it can not use the free space to host future data. If we add 1GB of data, the data file becomes 501GB. Even if we create and empty database and copy all data over, we will get another 500GB database which absolutely weird.

Any ways to decrease the size of this DB?

Comment: This question is better suited for http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The file cannot be? That's... existential for a database error.

Answer (score 0):

About shrink DB in Sql Server, I'm using this script:

```
USE db_name
GO
DBCC SHRINKFILE('phisycal DB name log', 1)
BACKUP LOG db_name TO DISK='NUL:'
DBCC SHRINKFILE('phisycal DB name log', 1)
GO
```

Tell me if it's OK

Comment: We are talking about data, not log

Comment: DBCC SHRINKFILE apply file DB shrink, instead of LOG file, put the phisycal name of data file and remove BACKUP LOG line. Tell me if it's OK.